# HashMap implementation where there are inputs from two classes

Tags: java, hashmap

The hashmap declaration is as follows:

```
HashMap<Employee, Hobby> hm = new HashMap<Employee, Hobby>()
```

There is a hobby class and employee class.
I have applied a method:

```
public void addEmployees(HashMap<Employee, Hobby> hm)
{
    public void addEmployees(int num, HashMap<Employee, Hobby> hm)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter name of employee");
            String name = sc.next();
            hm.put(name);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error at the `hm.put(name)` line and I do not know how to include the Hobby class attributes here as values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You need to share something that you have tried, which language you are using and any specific issue with that.

Comment: Please update your question with relevant details - what  you have done, what issue you are facing instead of asking a generic question to someone to write a "method" for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code. First of all, you cannot create nested method definitions. The other problem is your usage of the `put` method - it requires you to specify a key and a value. Your HashMap is a Map from `Employee` to `Hobby`, so you need to pass an employee parameter first and then a hobby:

```
hm.put(new Employee(name), new Hobby(hobby));
       ^------key-------^  ^----value-----^
```

You may need to get the hobby from the user first, in much the same way as you read the `name` from the input.

Not directly related to the question, but your `for` loop seems incorrect too - you will have one more prompt than the parameter specified for `num`.

```
for(int i=0;i<=num;i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                  *
```

Comment: Thanks alot..it worked..can u please help me how to display those elements..cos there are two classes and i am using iterator

Comment: I can't help you much without some code, but you probably need to implement the `toString()` method in your `Employee` and `Hobby` classes.

Comment: public void displayEmployees(HashMap<Employee,Hobby>hm){
         Set s=hm.keySet();
         Iterator iterator=s.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Employee emp=(Employee)iterator.next();
           
            System.out.println(emp.getEmployeeID());
            System.out.println(emp.getSalary());
            System.out.println(emp.getName());
            Hobby hob=(Hobby)iterator.next();
            System.out.println(hob.getHobbyDescription());
            System.out.println(hob.getHobbyName());
            
            
        }

Comment: You should take a look into [iterating over maps](https://www.google.de/search?q=java+iterate+over+map). Your iterator will only return `Employee`s, which you would know if you used generic types (`Set<Employee>`, `Iterator<Employee>`).

Answer (score 1):

When you add to a map in java, the method requires two parameters

```
hm.put(key,value)
```

So in your case you need something like this

```
System.out.println("Enter name of employee");
String name=sc.next();
System.out.println("Enter hobby");
String hobby=sc.next();
hm.put(new Employee(name),new Hobby(hobby));
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help